# Wilson loop as path integral of parallel transport action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, wilson-loop

I am trying to get that the path integral of the parallel transport action is the Wilson loop. Here is the setting:

Let $w$ be a complex vector dimension $N$, and $A_{\mu}$ a fixed Yang-Mills connection. We will work with $G=SU(N)$. Using the parallel transport equation and the constraint:

$$i\frac{dw}{d\tau} = \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau} A_{\mu}w$$
$$w^{\dagger}w=1 $$
We construct the following action with a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ enforcing the constraint above. Evidently the equation of motion of this action is the parallel transport equation.
$$S_w = \int  \left(i w^{\dagger}\frac{dw}{dt} + \lambda(w^{\dagger}w-1)+w^{\dagger}A(x(\tau))w \right)d\tau$$

This vector satisfies:
$$[w_i,w_j^{\dagger}]=\delta_{ij}$$

Now let $\tau \in \mathbf{S}$ to allow for large gauge transformations. I finally arrive to the following path integral, where I had to insert the $w_i$ factors for it to not vanish:

$$ Z_w[A]= \int e^{iS_w (w;\lambda;A)} w_i(\tau=\infty)w_i^{\dagger}(\tau=-\infty) \mathcal{D}\lambda\mathcal{D}w \mathcal{D}w^{\dagger}$$

I am supposed to get that

$$Z_w[A] = tr \mathcal{P}e^{i\int A d\tau}$$

How do I compute that specific path integral?

Comment: I think, that commutation equation, that you wrote, are in canonical quantization. But you are interested in path integral quantization of such system, right?

Comment: Yes. I was providing background for both quantizations, but mainly I'm interested in path integral.

Comment: Is it obvious, that path integral vanishes, if one didn't inserted $w_i$ factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will follow [Monopoles and Wilson Lines](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6167), by David Tong, Kenny Wong.

Let's work in **perturbation theory**. Action:
$$
S_w = \int  \left(i w^{\dagger}\frac{dw}{dt} + \alpha(w^{\dagger}w-\kappa)+w^{\dagger}A(x(\tau))w \right)d\tau
$$
Propogator for free (non-interacting) part of action, in following we use $\langle \dots \rangle$ for averaging by free theory:
$$
\langle w_i^\dagger(\tau_1) w_j(\tau_2)\rangle = \theta(\tau_1-\tau_2) \delta_{ij}
$$

1. **Vacuum bubbles**

As usual in perturbation theory, we can factorise vacuum diagrams. You will obtain up to notations:

[image]

All $n ≥ 2$ factors vanish because the product of the step functions vanishes everywhere except on a set of measure zero.
So we have only one contribution ($\theta(0)=1/2$):
$$
\exp\left(i (N/2 - \kappa )\int dt\; \alpha(t)\right)
=
\exp\left(-i \kappa_{eff} \int dt\; \alpha(t)\right)
$$

2. **Path integral with insertions**

$$
Z_w[A]= \int\mathcal{D}\lambda\mathcal{D}w \mathcal{D}w^{\dagger}\; e^{iS_w (w;\lambda;A)} w_i(\tau=\infty)w_i^{\dagger}(\tau=-\infty)
$$

This integral correspond to following series of diagrams (times to vacuum bubbles factor):

[image]

This series correspondence to:
[image]

Including vacuum bubbles we left with:

$$
Z_\omega[A] = W[A]\int D\alpha e^{-i\int dt \;\alpha(t) (\kappa_{eff}-1)}
$$

If $\kappa_{eff}= 1$, we obtain:

$$
Z_\omega[A] = W[A]
$$

Comment: Could you summarize why without insertion of the $w$ and $w^{\dagger}$ the path integral vanishes? Also, what would be the difference if there is no $\lambda$ apart from not conserving the norm of $w$?

Comment: Without insertion you will have only $\int D\alpha e^{-i\int dt \alpha(t)\kappa_{eff}}= \delta(\kappa_{eff})$.

Comment: What about without imposing $\alpha$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. $\alpha$ is present in action from initial step.

Comment: My question is, what would happen to the path integral if $\alpha$ were not included in the action from the beginning? Would it lead to the same answer for $\kappa =1$?

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona If you didn't include $\alpha$, you will need to deal with constraint system, and can't simply integrate over $w$ and $w^\dagger$, you must solve constraint.. Second question is not clear yo me, try reformulate, please..

Comment: How would one integrate over $w$ and $w^{\dagger}$ imposing constraint if not with $\alpha$? My second question is the following. The equation before the last one that you wrote has a $e^{i \int (\alpha (\kappa_{eff} -1))dt}$ term. The integral vanishes with the choice of $\kappa$, so the answer does not seem to depend on $\alpha$ in the end?

Comment: 1) It is hard task. So to avoid this, usually introduce $\alpha$. 2) Answer is independent of alpha, because you integrate out $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh, I meant. When you set $\kappa = 1$, then you have $Z_w[A] = W[A] \int \mathcal{D}\alpha$. Why is this integral 1?

Comment: Yes, formally this integral is infinity, so you need be ore careful when deal with correlators. You need divide integral by average of identity operator. Infinity will be  cancel.